# What's the difference/relationship between CreateIndex and HasIndex

Tags: entity-framework-core

I can't seem to find any documentation on this, at least not on docs.microsoft, although I've Googled enough to no avail.

I'm seeing the following two pieces of code below:

```
// In a migration Up
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex
                 (
                   name: "IX_UserQualificationEndorsement_UserId_QualificationId_InstitutionId",
                   table: "UserQualificationEndorsement",
                   columns: new[] { "UserId", "QualificationId", "InstitutionId" },
                   unique: true
                 );

// In DbContext.OnModelCreating
modelBuilder.Entity<UserQualificationEndorsement>()
            .HasIndex
            (
               userQualificationEndorsement => new
               {
                 userQualificationEndorsement.UserId,
                 userQualificationEndorsement. QualificationId,
                 userQualificationEndorsement. InstitutionId
               }
            )
            .IsUnique();
```

**Suspicion:** My knowledge of Fluent API is not that great, but as far as I can tell, `HasIndex` is used to automatically scaffold `CreateIndex` instructions in the next migration that's added.

**Question:** Is my suspicion above correct and if so, does `HasIndex` serve any other purpose?

Comment: You can check the answer in this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/

Comment: @kwingkwing.ko That does not help me at all. Could you narrow your link down to an actual page that addresses my question? For example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes.

Comment: Just go to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.hasindex?view=efcore-2.1

And you can search the API keyword there (e.g., HasIndex, CreateIndex)

Comment: @kwingkwing.ko Again, this does not help me. Or anyone. I know where to find API documentation, that's clearly not what I'm after if you read the question.